# SVG clippath not working with foreignObject in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, mask, clip-path

I'm trying to get a video mask of some text, overlayed on top of another instance of video. I've achieved the desired effect in FF:

[image]

The Text overlay masking the an instance of the same video it is overlayed on top of. I used the following code to do this:

```
<video id="bkg" src="/locations.mp4" autoplay loop></video>

<svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<clippath id="cp-circle">
    <text
    text-anchor="middle"
    x="50%"
    y="98%"
    >TEXT TEXT</text>
</clippath>

<g clip-path="url(#cp-circle)">
    <foreignObject width="853" x="0"
                                 y="0" height="480">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <video id="bkg2" src="/locations.mp4" autoplay loop></video>

        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
<script>
        document.getElementById("bkg").playbackRate = 0.8;
</script>
```

In Chrome this simply renders the two videos on top of each other, with no masking. Any idea why or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not support SVG foreignObject correctly. WebKit bug (Filed). See http://svgdesign.guru for example.